# How to get the instance monitoring type (basic vs detailed) using boto?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

How can I get the instance monitoring type (basic vs detailed) using boto? I need it to know the sampling interval of metrics.

I am not finding it in the API.

Link to boto EC2 API: http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#module-boto.ec2.volume

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An EC2 instance has Basic monitoring by default.  There is no way to turn it off.  You can also enable Detailed monitoring either by specifying `monitoring_enabled=True` when calling `run_instances` or by calling `monitor_instances` on existing instances.

To determine whether you have detailed monitoring enabled or not, call `get_all_instances` and then look at the `monitoring_state` attribute of the returned `Instance` object.  It will have a value of `enabled` if detailed monitoring is enabled and a value of `disabled` if basic monitoring is being used.

Comment: Thanks. It infact returns `"disabled"` if it is not enabled and not `None`. I was able to get this info after posting the question, but did not know that disabled means it is only basic monitoring! Thanks for making the connection.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected my answer to avoid confusion for future readers.